# Change fontSize of ListView with ctrl + mousewheel

Tags: c#, listview, zooming, font-size

I have a ListView (**auftraegeView**). Of this ListView I whish to change the FontSize of its Items through Ctrl + MouseWheel aka. a simple zoom like in excel or a browser.

In the form's ctor I subscribed my method to the event

```
        this.MouseWheel += scrollZoom;
```

My EventHandler calculates the new FontHeight and applies it, if it doesn't exceed the bounds. The RowHeight is always kept a little bigger, finally I resize the columns so the zoom also works on the horizontal scale.

```
private void scrollZoom(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Control)
            return;

        int currFontHeight = ListViewFontHeight;

        int delta = (e.Delta)/120;

        int newFontHeight = currFontHeight + delta;

        if(newFontHeight < 1 || newFontHeight > 150)
            return;

        ListViewFontHeight = newFontHeight;
        ListViewRowHeight = ListViewFontHeight + 4;

        auftraegeView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
    }
```

ListViewFontHeight **gets** the Font.Height of the first Item. (Value is identical across all Items, so the first is as good as any.)

The **set** is where the issue seems to be (see below). My idea is that I just go through each Item and change the Font.

```
    private int ListViewFontHeight
    {
        get { return auftraegeView.Items[0].Font.Height; }

        set
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem line in auftraegeView.Items)
            {
                line.Font = new Font(line.Font.FontFamily, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

**ISSUE / QUESTION**
Regardless of the direction I scroll in, the FontSize only *increases* till it hits the ceiling. The rest works fine (setting ListViewRowHeight, detecting the event at all,...).
What might be causing this?

Comment: Take your calculations into float, so you can't truncate to 0 during the division.

Comment: @TaW added for better overall quality, but that wouldn't explain my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
delta = (e.Delta > 0? 1 : -1);
```

to be on the safe side for different mouse settings.

This works for me:

```
 float delta = (e.Delta > 0 ? 2f : -2f);
 listView1.Font = new Font (listView1.Font.FontFamily, listView1.Font.Size + delta);
```

Comment: Added that, but that would just mean that on different mouses "smaller" and "bigger" are switched, not "you can only make it bigger".
I found the Issue though.

Comment: I found [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25738281/7332500) helpful also: "If you can't see the 'MouseWheel' event on a component, then you need to create it manually"

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself:

In the ListViewFontHeight - property the get accessor used **Item.Font.Height** instead of **Item.Font.Size**

```
private int ListViewFontHeight
    {
        get { return (int)auftraegeView.Items[0].Font.Size; } //works now
```