# how do i scroll panel with all controll using mouse or touch window form

Tags: c#, scroll, panel, scrollable

I want to scroll using mouse or touch on click and drag.

[i just want to scroll on click panel area and scroll controls of the panel's.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfbVO.jpg)

Comment: Please add code to show what you've been doing, what you expect, and what's going wrong

Comment: It is for WinForms? Then add a tag. It can be any other GUI *(not only Android, but there are also many other GUI frameworks)*. Since you say touch, it still can be Windows, but it os desktop Windows, or Mobile Windows? What have you done so far? What is your code? What control *(the scrollable)* are you using? Are you processing Mouse wheel event? See [this qeustion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4429901/2826535) and also answers to see how to handle mouse wheel.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: C#,Windows Form