# How do I make the mouse wheel scrolls in richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, scroll, richtextbox

I want the mouse wheel scrolls up and down within  richTextBox

Comment: You put the cursor in the richTextBox and you move your mouse wheel up and down?

Comment: Make that ! instead of ?

Comment: You have to *click* in the RichTextBox control first. Then you can roll the mouse wheel. Works fine every time.

Comment: There is a scenario where this question makes sense and the answer is not so obvious. In my case where there was a richTextBox on the form but the vertical scrollbar shown was not for the richTextBox it was for an underlying panel. The mouse wheel scroll was having no effect because the panel with the scrollbars was not getting focus. I found the solution to this problem over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4766428/649497

Answer (score 0):

You can set the focus property to the TextBox, to scroll by using the mouse wheel.

```
TextBox.Focus();
```

Comment: Is this a windows standard that the control must have focus to scroll with the mouse wheel? I suspect the OP expected scrolling without focus as I would also expect.